# What is the difference between camera.transform and pointOfView

Tags: ios, camera, transform, scenekit, arkit

For placing object in front of the camera, I see there are 2 ways: using `camera.transform` and `pointOfView`

**camera.transform** is from `SCNView` and `scnView.session.currentFrame.camera.transform` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera

> The position and orientation of the camera in world coordinate space.

Here is how to use it

```
var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
translation.columns.3.z = -2
node.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
```

**pointOfView** is from `SCNView` and `scnView.pointOfView` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523982-pointofview

> The node from which the scene’s contents are viewed for rendering

Here is how it is used, using `convertPosition` to convert to world coordinate

```
let camera = scnView.pointOfView!
let position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -2)
node.position = camera.convertPosition(position, to: nil)
```

What is the difference between these 2? Both seems to refer to the camera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`session`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2865796-session) property is exposed by [`ARSCNView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview), not directly by `SCNView`. ARKit uses its session's camera transform to drive the SceneKit scene's point of view, so in this case they match. But not every SceneKit application uses ARKit, and in this case orientating the point of view is the responsibility of the developer.